# Overriding CSS Grid Properties using Media Queries

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid

**Original Code**

```
    section.new-features { 
    .new-features-right-col {
            .wrapper-newfeatures {
                 margin-top: 3em;
                 display: grid;
                 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
                 grid-column-gap: 31px;
                 grid-row-gap: 30px;
              }
    }
```

**Media Query**

```
    section.new-features {
        .wrapper-newfeatures {
             display: grid;
             grid-template-columns: auto;
             grid-gap: 2em;
             width: 90%;
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I'm having difficulties overriding CSS Grid Properties within my media query section. Whenever I set the grid-template-columns: auto; which is only suppose to use **one (1)** grid column it gets overridden by the original code and uses six columns. I tried to troubleshoot this by using a ancestor element by typing **body** behind the CSS class but this doesn't seem to work. If anyone could assist me with this problem or help me approach this, it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of auto use 1fr.